# Flags mismatch irq 32 Driver A vs Driver A

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, imx6

Generally flag mismatch is for  driver A vs Driver B. Could you give some pointers to solve. We are using imx6ul board.
What is the way to debug this.
I have checked others driver as well and none of them is registering irq 32.
It looks like we are registering same driver twice.

Erorr:

```
[ 7.315153] input: 20cc000.snvs:snvs-powerkey as /devices/soc0/soc/2000000.aips-bus/20cc000.snvs/20cc000.snvs:snvs-powerkey/input/input0
[ 7.332058] genirq: Flags mismatch irq 32. 00000004 (20cc000.snvs:snvs-powerkey) vs. 00000004 (20cc000.snvs:snvs-powerkey)
[ 7.343879] snvs_pwrkey 20cc000.snvs:snvs-powerkey: interrupt not available.
[ 7.366705] snvs_pwrkey: probe of 20cc000.snvs:snvs-powerkey failed with error -16
[ 7.394971] snvs_rtc 20cc000.snvs:snvs-rtc-lp: registered as rtc0
```

DTS

```
snvs: snvs@020cc000 {
    compatible = "fsl,sec-v4.0-mon", "syscon", "simple-mfd";
    reg = <0x020cc000 0x4000>;
    
snvs_rtc: snvs-rtc-lp {
    compatible = "fsl,sec-v4.0-mon-rtc-lp";
    regmap = <&snvs>;
    offset = <0x34>;
    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 19 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>,
    <GIC_SPI 20 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    };

snvs_poweroff: snvs-poweroff {
    compatible = "syscon-poweroff";
    regmap = <&snvs>;
    offset = <0x38>;
    value = <0x61>;
    mask = <0x61>;
    status = "disabled";
    };
    
snvs_pwrkey: snvs-powerkey {
    compatible = "fsl,sec-v4.0-pwrkey";
    regmap = <&snvs>;
    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 4 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    linux,keycode = <KEY_POWER>;
    wakeup-source;
    };
    };
```

Comment: So, what prevents you to drop outdated section from DTS?

Comment: It was error in the source code. Request_irq was being called twice.

Comment: @KamleshGurudasani So is this problem actually solved by not calling the irq request twice?

Comment: Yes @Micrified, problem got solved after removing the second instance of irq_request

Comment: @KamleshGurudasani Thanks. I'm having a similar problem with the PMIC ON/OFF, but I don't get get any kernel output from the `snvs_pwrkey` driver. It's good to see this example worked for you though. I appreciate the response!